# PHP Post with visualbasic .NEt

Tags: php, mysql, vb.net

I am programming since years in Visualbasic.Net.
Actually I start up to develop tools for Bee-Keeping, and  for this I need to send/request data to Mysql database in my weebside at OVH.
This is completely new for me, and I have some difficulties to find how to do this.
i want to progress in 3 steps:-

1. launch by vb.net a PHP programm stored on the webside that makes un action without parameters, like empty a table of database.
2. launch a PHP programm with parameters sent by vb.net, to make for example an SQL-INSERT
3. lauch PHP programm with SQL Select, and get back the result

I test step 1, and have some troubles. It works always 1 or 2 times, then it keeps blocked some time.

Can someone tell me whats wrong ?
I tested the PHP file itself, by copying in index.php, in this case no problem, it works fine at each update of webpage in browser.

here is the vb.net code i created by examples found on the net.

thanks

```
Dim PostData = "  "
    Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://steinhilber.eu/prog1.php")

    ClientSocket = New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient()
    request.Method = "POST"
    Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PostData)
    request.ContentType = "application/x-form-urlencoded"
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
    Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    Stream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
    Stream.Flush()
    Stream.Close()
    ClientSocket = Nothing
```

Comment: Have a look at the error log on your server, probably your requests are blocked and the reason is written to the log

Comment: Is your request triggering an error on the client?  If possible, please edit your question to include what *is* happening.